# Why setting a value of global array has impact on executable file?

Tags: c++, g++, c++20

When I set my array to {1,1}, size of the executable file increase from 10 KiB to 7 MiB. But when I set it to {}, the size doesn't change.

```
long long fib[1000001] = {1,1}; // 7 MiB
```

```
long long fib[1000001] = {}; // 10 KiB
```

I use C++20 and g++ 8.1.0.

It only happens with global variables and it doesn't matter what type of memory it uses.

Comment: This is platform specific, but compilers/linkers typically optimize memory for global variables that are all zero bytes by not storing them explicitly in the executable. Instead the memory for such variables gets allocated and initialised when the program is loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a global variable is initialized to zero, the executable does not have to contain actual storage for it. It merely needs to tell the OS's executable loader that "I need X storage of bytes for global data", and the loader will provide that. That memory will be zeroed out.

However, if a global variable is initialized to something non-zero, even partially, then its data has to come from somewhere. The simplest solution is to generate the bytes of data at compile-time and shove them into the executable. At runtime, references to the global variable point into the loaded executable's storage.

While this is platform/OS specific, it's generally how most executables and compilers work